# How to change width of flip toggle switch mini?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery, togglebutton

I am unable to change the width of a mini version of a flip toggle switch, and the text is not all shown.

If it is not mini, I can change the width using the technique of adding this to the CSS:

```
 .containing-element .ui-slider-switch { width: 7em }
```

and then enveloping the switch in a div.

Doing exactly the same if I set data-mini="true", and the toggle becomes mini, but I cannot change the width.

How can I change the width if the flip toggle switch is mini?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

It looks like that if you add !important to your css, it works.  Try

```
.containing-element 
.ui-slider-switch { width: 7em !important }
```

Happy coding!

Comment: This wont work for data-mini="true" elements, you need to add the .ui-mini class to the css

Comment: You are probably right - I never checked that option before.

Answer (score 0):

When using ui-mini you need to mention that in the css as well, Try this

```
.containing-element .ui-slider-switch.ui-mini { width: 7em }
```